# unable to do collpase/expand using telerik radgrid (Grid - Multi-Column Headers)

Tags: telerik, radgrid

When I am using telerik radgrid I am getting issue on Collpase/Expand with ColumnGroups property. I am getting error like **"Type 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView' does not have a public property named 'ColumnGroups'."**

I used below link to achieve the drag to group by the grid columns but I stuck up with this collapse/expand issue while grouping it.

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/multi-column-headers/defaultcs.aspx

I will be very happy if anyone resolved it.

Comment: please upgrade to this or the latest version to use MultiColumn Headers as demonstrated in the following demo: [link](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/columns-rows/columns/multi-column-headers/defaultcs.aspx)